# how do I use dynamic controls with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a scenario that I'm attempting to apply knockout to with some problems. Basically I have this sort of ui

```
Add (create a new Select Box duo with delete button)

Select Box  (options = Json from ajax request)
Select Box  (options = Json from ajax request with param from 1st select)
Delete

Select Box 
Select Box 
Delete
```

etc

Each row I regard as another Widget in the array so my knockout for simplicity

```
var ViewModel = function (widgets) {

    var self = this;

    this.widgets= ko.observableArray(widgets);
    this.subWidgets= ko.observableArray();

    this.mySelections = ko.observableArray();

   this.selectedWidget.subscribe(function (name) {

        if (name != null) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddSubWidgetsByName")',
                data: { name: name },
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {

                    self.subWidgets(result);

                }
            });
        }
    } .bind(this));

    self.addWidget = function (widget) {
        self.mySelections.push({

            ??? profit
        });
    };

}
var viewiewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewiewModel);

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AddFund")',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {

        viewModel.widgets(result);


    }
});
 <select id="widgets" 
                data-bind='
                    options: widgets, 
                    optionsValue : "Name", 
                    optionsText: "Name", 
                    optionsCaption: "[Please select a widgets]"'
                    value: selectedWidget,
```

>

Can I dynamically create a select for each widget and relate the subwidget selection to an item in mySelections array? I can't use the value binding for selectedWidget in quite this way as all dropdowns are bound together in this manner. I need to make them independant - any ideas on how to go about that?

Cheers!

Comment: First, you are subscribing to a non-existent property. But, your best bet is a widget viewmodel, so that each widget manages itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to make each widget its own viewmodel (note, this is from jsFiddle, so the ajax is done to work with their echo API, which requires POST):

```
var Widget = function(){
var self = this;
self.selectedWidget = ko.observable('');
self.subWidgets = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selectedSubWidget = ko.observable('');

this.selectedWidget.subscribe(function (name) {
    if (name != null) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"/echo/json/",
            data: {
                json: $.toJSON(
                    [Math.floor(Math.random()*11),
                     Math.floor(Math.random()*11),
                     Math.floor(Math.random()*11)]
                ),
                delay: 1
            },
            type:"POST",
            success:function(response)
            {
                self.subWidgets(response);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

};

You could then easily track sub-selections and additions with a simple viewmodel. Here is the [complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLYFT/).